# How to show $\binom{2n}{n} \ge \prod_{n < p \le 2n} p $?

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, analytic-number-theory

What is the best way to show 
\begin{equation}
\binom{2n}{n} \ge \prod_{n < p \le 2n} p
\end{equation}
for prime $p$.

I know that $ 2^{2n} = (1+1)^{2n} \ge \binom{2n}{n}$.

and 
\begin{equation}
\binom{2n}{n} = \frac{2n(2n-1)...(n+1)}{n!}
\end{equation}

Comment: Can the factors $p$ for $n < p \leqslant 2n$ be cancelled?

Comment: Is $p$ supposed to be prime? Otherwise it doesn't look true, unless you have the inequality backwards in what you're trying to prove.

Comment: yes for prime $p$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually something stronger holds. It turns out that the product in question **divides** the binomial coefficient.

Why is this? Well we know that the binomial coefficient is a positive integer. Also any prime $n<p\leq 2n$ must divide this positive integer since $p|(2n)!$ and $p\nmid n!$.

Comment: I figured OP probably meant $p$ prime. I asked for clarification, and if they do mean $p$ prime then I'll give this +1.

Comment: Well this is quite a well known result so has probably been found somewhere else and copied.

Comment: $p$ must be prime otherwise the inequality doesn't make sense. Very clever answer! Entirely by reasoning, without a single line of equation required. (+1)

Comment: I think you mean p doesnt divide $n!$?

Comment: That's what I wrote.